# Как в Postgres найти 2 ближайших записи с разными событиями?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет!

Есть такой запрос

```
 select 
       dialog_id,
       agent_id,
       "event",
       created_on_tz,
       to_char(created_on_tz, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date"
     from chat_dialog_event 
     where 
       agent_id = 2 and 
       ("event" = 'START' or "event" = 'RESPONSE') 
       and (created_on_tz between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-15') order by created_on_tz
```

Он возвращает таблицу Ивентов по определенным условиям

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне в выборке оставить все строки с событием RESPONSE и ближайшие к ним события START в рамках одного dialog_id.

То есть я хочу сформировать по каждому диалогу пары дата старта и дата ответа, а потом я уже для них буду считать время реакции и высчитывать среднее время.

Подобный запрос я составлял, но он в рамках одного dialog_id брал максимальные значения по этим события. Иногда бывают события START бывают без события RESPONSE - в такой ситуации взяв максимальные значения я имею потом в результате отрицательное значение при вычитании.

**UPDATE:** Решение от @Akina дало желаемый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правда не ясно, что делать, если придет сначала 2 start, а потом 2 responce

Comment: @Mike, в рамках одного dialog_id не может получиться такого. ```start``` - это событие при создании диалога - ```response``` - это событие возникает, только при первом сообщении на этот диалог. То есть в рамках одного диалога и одного агента, диалог может много раз стартануть (допустим f5, обрыв связи) и после этих стартов будет только респонс - это первый сценарий. 2 сценарий - когда респонса вообще не было, то есть диалог стартанул и его потом закрыли без ответа (такие сразу записи не нужны)

Comment: Еще возможен 3 вариант: старт - респонс - вдруг обрыв связи(например) снова старт, снова респонс

Comment: короче пробуйте предложенный Akina lead и смотрите на всех данных все ли ситуации ловит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
WITH cte AS (   select dialog_id,
                       agent_id,
                       "event",
                       created_on_tz,
                       to_char(created_on_tz, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date",
                       LEAD(event) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id 
                                         ORDER BY created_on_tz) prev_event,
                       LAG(event) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id 
                                        ORDER BY created_on_tz) next_event
                from chat_dialog_event 
                where agent_id = 2 
                  and ("event" = 'START' or "event" = 'RESPONSE') 
                  and (created_on_tz between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-15') 
)
SELECT dialog_id,
       agent_id,
       "event",
       created_on_tz,
       "date"
FROM cte
WHERE ("event" = 'RESPONSE' AND prev_event = 'START')
   OR (next_event = 'RESPONSE' AND "event" = 'START')
order by created_on_tz;
```

Comment: Вроде получилось) Сейчас скриншот закину в описание задачи

Comment: @shub1nk Проверь, я подредактировал запрос. Поначалу чёта упустил, что "в рамках одного dialog_id".

Comment: @до правки вариант дал решение, которое добавил к описанию. А после правки только 1 пара осталась, но там СТАРТ позже РЕСПОНСА

Comment: @shub1nk *до правки вроде вариант лучше был* До правки он был неправильным  логически. Но если гарантируется, что диалог всегда начинается STARTом и диалоги не пересекаются по времени, то да, можно партиционирование убрать. *там СТАРТ позже РЕСПОНСА* Ой, поменяй имена у LEAD и LAG в cte местами, делов-то. Я их вечно путаю...

Comment: диалогов может быть много, и могут пересекаться по времени, поэтому, значит 2 вариант нужен. Поправил имена, получился желаемый результат